# How to run several python programs parallelly in shell script?

Tags: python, bash, shell

Currently I am using a for loop in shell script to run several programs one after another. How can I modify the script so that it can run several program at the same time?

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
for n in $(seq 0 9)
do
  echo $n
  YAML_PATH_NAME=('./data/setting_'$n'.yaml')
  echo $YAML_PATH_NAME
  python3 program.py --yaml_path $YAML_PATH_NAME
done
```

Comment: `python3 program.py --yaml_path $YAML_PATH_NAME &`

Comment: FWIW the multiprocessing library is designed to help with this: https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html

Comment: Put an '&' on the end of the line where you call Python, that will background that process and move to the next loop iteration without waiting for it to finish.